# nebula-test fails to load the project plugin class when using IntegrationSpec class

Tags: groovy, gradle, spock, nebula-test

I'm in the process of writing and testing a Gradle plugin.  When I try to test the plugin I get an error indicating the plugin class can't be found?  If I use the plugin id I get: Plugin with id <> not found. If I use the plugin class name I get: Could not find property 'com' on root project.

Below is the build.gradle, ExamplePlugin class and the Test Spec.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.sas'
version = '0.1.0'

description = "Project to test with nebula plugin."

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6' //version required
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile gradleApi()

    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3'
    testCompile 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-test:3.1.0'
}
```

**plugin class**

```
package com.sas.gradle.plugins.example

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.logger.debug("ExamplePlugin: Running...")
    }
}
```

**test class spec**

```
package com.sas.gradle.plugins.example

import nebula.test.IntegrationSpec
import nebula.test.functional.ExecutionResult

class ExamplePluginIntegSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def 'setup and display the buildscript classpath'() {
        writeHelloWorld('example.hello')
        buildFile << '''
            apply plugin: 'java'
            apply plugin: com.sas.gradle.plugins.example.ExamplePlugin
            task show << {
                buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it }
            }
        '''.stripIndent()

        when:
        ExecutionResult result = runTasksSuccessfully('show')

        then:
        result.standardOutput.contains(':show')
    }
}
```

It appears when using the IntegrationSpec it creates build scripts build.gradle and settings.gradle in build/test/***package***/***spec*** location.  Also, I see .gradle, .gradle-test-kit, src directories at the same location.  I was wondering how the .classpath is setup for running the tests and noticed an init.gradle script in the .gradle-test-kit; then in it I found a allprojects->buildscript->dependencies>classpath DSL.
Then I noticed my plugin class (compiled to build/classes/main) wasn’t in the list?  I’d have thought nebula-test IntegrationSpec class would have done this?  By adding this DSL:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('../../../../build/classes/main')
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help,
Jim

Lastly here's the exception I get:

```
Class com.sas.gradle.plugins.example.ExamplePluginIntegSpec
all > com.sas.gradle.plugins.example > ExamplePluginIntegSpec
1
tests
1
failures
0
ignored
3.173s
duration
0%
successful
Failed tests
Tests
Standard output
Standard error
setup and display the buildscript classpath

org.gradle.api.GradleException: Build aborted because of an internal error.
    at nebula.test.functional.internal.DefaultExecutionResult.rethrowFailure(DefaultExecutionResult.groovy:97)
    at nebula.test.IntegrationSpec.runTasksSuccessfully(IntegrationSpec.groovy:265)
    at com.sas.gradle.plugins.example.ExamplePluginIntegSpec.setup and display the buildscript classpath(ExamplePluginIntegSpec.groovy:19)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\Users\japoli\IdeaProjects\nebula-test-example-master\build\test\com.sas.gradle.plugins.example.ExamplePluginIntegSpec\setup-and-display-the-buildscript-classpath\build.gradle' line: 4
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'setup-and-display-the-buildscript-classpath'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:124)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:167)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher$1.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'setup-and-display-the-buildscript-classpath'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:153)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:495)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:103)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'com' on root project 'setup-and-display-the-buildscript-classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:97)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.java:66)
    at build_3ap3e1c6wmmpxvu497fssx7g9.run(C:\Users\japoli\IdeaProjects\nebula-test-example-master\build\test\com.sas.gradle.plugins.example.ExamplePluginIntegSpec\setup-and-display-the-buildscript-classpath\build.gradle:4)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 49 more
Wrap lines 
Generated by Gradle 2.6 at Jan 13, 2016 10:01:59 AM
```

Comment: Is that how your project looks like: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34771078 ? The test passess.

Comment: I just grabbed the code; it fails on my machine.  I'm running on Windows with Java version "1.8.0_25".  What environment are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.10.5, Java  "1.8.0_05"

Comment: Ok thanks, I jumped over to Linux 2.6 and it works there!

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Gradle TestKit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html) (the functional replacement for Nebula test)? Take a look at the [specific section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#N14A5F) about placing the code under test on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that certainly helps.  I'll give it a try.